# Changing an image using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I cannot figure out why this image is not changing. I'll provide the relevant HTML, CSS, and jQuery below.

**HTML**

```
<nav id="desktop-nav">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
  <div> ... </div> 
  ...
```

**CSS**

```
nav#desktop-nav .logo a {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url("../path/to/image-logo-white.png");
  background-size: 50px 50px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > $(window).height()) {
      $("nav#desktop-nav .logo a").attr("src", "../path/to/image-logo.png");
    }
})
```

**NOTE:**
I have tested this function, and it does work (I changed the color of text):

```
$("#desktop-nav #main-nav .main-nav-center .main-nav-list li a").css({"color":"black"});
```

Help me out here, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` doesn't has `src` attribute. So it wont work:

```
 $("nav#desktop-nav .logo a").attr("src", "../path/to/image-logo.png");
```

To solve this, the fast way I see:

CSS

```css
nav#desktop-nav .logo a {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url("../path/to/image-logo-white.png");
  background-size: 50px 50px;
}

nav#desktop-nav .logo a.another-logo {
    /* OVERRING ANOTHER LOGO HERE*/
   background-image: url("../path/to/image-logo.png");
}
```

jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > $(window).height()) {
      $("nav#desktop-nav .logo a").addClass('another-logo');
    }
    else {
       $("nav#desktop-nav .logo a").removeClass('another-logo');
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks man! This works perfectly, and I love this solution, I haven't worked much in jQuery or JavaScript, so this was really helpful.

Comment: Hey, I have another quick question, I cannot seem to fix this issue I am having, I might just need to post another question.